# discord.js v13 member presence is undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get user presence with the new discord.js version 13. I added the following intents to my connection:

```
const INTENTS = [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
]
```

But after using `guild.members.fetch()`, `presence` property is `undefined`

This is how I am trying to access it

```js
guild.members.fetch().then(members => { 
    const online = members.filter((member) => !member.user?.bot && member.user?.presence?.status != 'offline').map((member) => member); 
})
```

am I missing something? This use to work well with v12, has anything else changed?

To add more information, I do get `presence` information in the event `presenceUpdate`

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!newMember.user.bot && newMember.status != 'offline') {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the property?

Comment: `guild.members.fetch().then(members => {
                    const online = members.filter((member) => !member.user?.bot && member.user?.presence?.status != 'offline').map((member) => member);
                })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in v13 [`User.presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) isn’t a property. You will need [`GuildMember.presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence)

```js
guild.members.fetch().then(members => { 
    const online = members.filter((member) => !member.user?.bot && member.presence?.status != 'offline').map((member) => member); 
})
```